# Pass template down to capsuled grid column

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, kendo-ui-angular2

I capsuled a kendo-grid-column inside a new component using

```
<imx-gridColumn field="Count" title="Count">
...
</imx-gridColumn>
```

The component using `imx-gridColumn` is templated with

```
<kendo-grid-column #column field="{{field}}">
...
</kendo-grid-column>
```

So far so good. Now I like to do something like

```
<imx-gridColumn field="Message" title="A longer message">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <button (click)="ShowMessage(dataItem)">Show my message</button>
    </ng-template>
</imx-gridColumn>
```

to apply a template to this specific column. Other columns should use the standard template provided by the `kendo-grid-column`.

Is there an easy way to pass the `ng-template` to the `kendo-grid-column`? 
If there isn't, how can I alter the content of the column, that the button is used instead of a simple text?

**Edit**
After some research I was able to extract the template using `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) Template:TemplateRef<ElementRef>` which at least contains some data. But now I'm stuck on pushing this template to my `kendo-grid-column`.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found the solution to this problem, so I like to share it with others, who might face the same problmes as I did.
I don't post the complete files but only the parts that are important to the solution.

**GridColumn.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'imx-gridColumn',
    templateUrl: './GridColumn.component.html',
})

export class imx_GridColumnComponent
{
  ...
  @ContentChild('kendoGridCellTemplate') Template:TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
}
```

**GridColumn.component.html**

```
<kendo-grid-column field="{{field}}">
   ...
    <ng-template *ngIf="Template" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="Template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit:dataItem}"></ng-container>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

After that, you can pass the template to the grid column doing:

```
<imx-gridColumn field="Message" title="A longer message">
    <ng-template #kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <button (click)="ShowMessage(dataItem)">Show my message</button>
    </ng-template>
</imx-gridColumn>
```

Notice, that if you like to provide multiple templates, you have to add an identifier to get the right template to apply. I used the same names that kendo does for there directives and simply added the prefix "#" but you can use any name you like.

Comment: I can confirm this works with Angular9 and kendo-angular-grid version 4.6.3. thank you!